# Someone who can explain me how ReactionCollector function?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Hey i am new with js and discord js and got a problem, i dont understand how reactioncollector works maybe someone here can explain and help me with that code. Its for a Ticket System if the other code is needed ill send it :

```
.then(async (channel, message) => {
        
          let sent = await channel.send(`<@${user.id}>`, new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("Welcome to your ticket!")
            .setDescription("We will be with you shortly")
            .setColor("00ff00")

          );
          sent.react('');
          
            const filter = (reaction, user) => {

              if (reaction.emoji.name === ""){
                
              
                reaction.users.remove(user);
                reaction.message.channel.delete();
              }


            return reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id === message.author.id;  
          }
          const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: 15000 });

          collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
            console.log(`Collected ${reaction.emoji.name} from ${user.tag}`);
          });

          collector.on('end', collected => {
            console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`);
          });
              


          });
  
        
        }
      }
    }
)
```

Comment: seems pretty obvious, what don't you understand?

Comment: @FlashThunder if i is so obvious why don't you point out the mistake in his code? E.g. his `filter` function should only do filtering and not do any logic and the logic is put into the `collector.on` events.

Comment: @TinNguyen could you pls fix the code i got no clue

Comment: @TinNguyen oh sorry didn't read the question, only title... thought he just needs a step by step explanation on how it works :) My bad.

Comment: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ReactionCollectorOptions set `max` to 1 since you aren't expecting any more reaction. Delete `if (reaction.emoji.name === "") {...}` and put `reaction.message.channel.delete();` into your `collectors.on collect` event. You don't need `collector.on end` I don't use javascript or discord.js so if there is an error you need to post the traceback.

Comment: Explanation after the changes: The `collector.on collect` event is called whenever a valid reaction is received. A valid reaction is received when the `filter` method you defined returns true. So if you are reacting with `` it will call that event. If someone else reacts nothing happens. If you react with a different emoji nothing happens.  
The `collect.on end` event is called when the ReactionCollector stops collecting. E.g. the time times out or a different condition was fulfilled (collected enough reactions). But for your use case this event is irrelevant.

Comment: Okay thanks ill try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the right filter. As I can see, you want to only detect  reaction from the message author. So put these restrictions into the filter and then every reaction collected by the collector will respect these conditions.

Now that you have this, just execute whatever you want and stop the collector once everything is done so you will not listen to any other reactions.

```js
let sent = await channel.send(`<@${user.id}>`, new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle("Welcome to your ticket!")
  .setDescription("We will be with you shortly")
  .setColor("00ff00")
);
sent.react('');

const filter = (reaction, user) => {
  //We filter the collector to only listen to  reaction added by the author of the message.
  return reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id === message.author.id;  
}
const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: 15000 });

collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
  console.log(`Collected ${reaction.emoji.name} from ${user.tag}`);
  reaction.users.remove(user);
  reaction.message.channel.delete();
  //Then we stop the collector.
  collector.stop()
});
```

Comment: Sorry for my inactivity, but thanks for helping me with that !! now i really understand collector